# if or elif either true then do something

Tags: python, python-2.7

this is just for academic interest. I encounter the following situation a lot.

```
either_true = False
if x:
  ...do something1
  either_true = True
elif y:
  ...do something2
  either_true = True
if either_true:
  ..do something3
```

is there any pythonic way of doing it, or in general better programming way of doing it.
Basically do something3 executes only if or elif is true.

Comment: It looks like your current solution is optimal. Other approaches, like ChrisProsser's answer, require evaluating `x` and/or `y` more than once.

Comment: Put something3 in a function, and call it from both branches.

Comment: This would be a prime case for ```if...else...finally```, too bad that doesn't exist.

Comment: @wnnmaw -- I disagree.  I would expect `finally` to execute no matter what -- Not if only one of the clauses was true-ish.

Comment: I've had code like this, but there was stuff between the if..elif and the if, in which case I really think this is the best solution

Comment: I don't know python, but another way could be setting either_true in both do_something1 and do_something2.

Comment: Thanks Guys for coming up with smart suggestions. By the way till now I like ChrisProsser and Bakiriu suggestions. If x, y are simple expressions then ChirProsser's looks ok, else Bakiriu's solution will do the job efficiently.

Comment: I would go with your solution. It may even reduce the code duplication in long run. The other answers are depending on the fact that you are running one line of code but when you put the duplicate code in each condition it will become larger and will violate dry code principal. but the most optimal solution might be what you already do up there.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Your code is *almost* optimal, as far as code repetition and evaluation are concerned. The only thing I can think of to avoid repetition would be:

```
# be optimistic!
either_true = True
if x:
    do_something1
elif y:
    do_something2
else:
    either_true = False

if either_true:
    do_something3
```

This removes one assignment, although the total number of lines doesn't change.

The advantage is that this works with `n` conditions, without adding any other assignment, while your current solution requires an `either_true = True` for every condition.

In my opinion they have about the same degree of readability, but the above code will be better with more conditions.

Also there's no "pythonic" way other then a readable solution that avoids code repetition and is optimal in terms of efficiency, and I don't know of any kind of "better programming" to achieve the same result.

Comment: This definitely improves the concept smartly

Comment: This is a good answer for the specific question, but if there was another 'elif' where either_true should be false, it wouldn't be very beneficial. The original question was of 'academic interest', so it's not likely that it should be limited to only one elif statement.

Comment: @Alex Actually you can just put the `either_true=False` on each branch where it should be `False`. Depending on the number of branches you can choose to use `True` or `False` as default to minimize the number of assignments. As I clearly stated in my answer, if we generalize in the case where you have `n` conditions and you want the variable to be true if *any* of those is true, then the code in my answer is the optimal solution. Also I don't see how other answers take this into account.

Comment: A downside of this is that related code (e.g. `do_something1` followed by `do_something3`) can be dozens of lines apart, you have to jump down while reading the code. All just because you don't want to repeat `do_something3` - and the reason for trying so hard to avoid repeating it is most certainly because it's more than a single function call. Adding a piece of state (the `either_true`) variable seems like a workaround to the problem that `do_something3` is too much code to make repeating it right where it should happen (right beneath `do_something1`, for instance) viable.

Answer (score 35):

You could also omit the `either_true` flag completely if `doSomething3` is a single line of code (e.g. a function call):

```
if x:
  ..do something 1
  ..do something 3
elif y:
  ..do something 2
  ..do something 3
```

It maintains the nice property of evaluating `x` and `y` at most once (and `y` won't be evaluated if `x` is true).

Comment: Wait. Maybe I'm a noob, but what if it's a call to a very complex function?

Comment: If `do something 3` is a function call, then yes, that's great. I would take this over the boolean approach.

Comment: @Dunno A complex function won't hurt. A complex function call (e. g. with many arguments) might be wrapped in a `lambda` before and then executed via the lambda.

Comment: and if it's not a function call, it can probably be turned into one.

Comment: @Dunno what would it matter if it's a call to a complex function? It would be called either way.

Comment: This can be fragile if more items are added later, such as elif z, elif a. The programmer has to remember to add `do something 3` to each branch.

Comment: @ZanLynx With the boolean they have to remember to set `either_true = True`, and with the nested if statements they have to remember to add `z` in two places.  It's inevitable something would have to be added somewhere when a third (or more) cases are added, but this IMO is the most maintainable.

Comment: Obviously the question is irrelevant if do something3 is a one liner.

Comment: @user1572215 Maybe the key insight is that there are only advantages to `doSomething3` to be a one-liner, so moving the code to a separate function is a good idea anyway because on the positive implications for the callers.

Comment: I don't like this because it violates DRY. If "do something 3" changes, you have to remember to change it twice, which could easily lead to bugs.

Comment: @thedayturns I guess wasn't explicit enough: IMHO the best fix is to move whatever code `doSomething3` stands for into a separate function. This (as @user1572215 correctly pointed out) also obsoletes the question.

Comment: It might be worthwhile to point out that the order of `if x` or `y` can be important. For example, if `y` is a lot more likely then `x` then you probably want if `y` first otherwise two conditional checks need to be done. As always, best to actually test the performance of each in case the compiler is doing any other optimization that makes this counter-productive.

Answer (score 19):

I would handle this by using nested if statements i.e.

```
if x or y:
    if x:
        ...do something1
    elif y:
        ...do something2
    ...do something3
```

As some comments have pointed out, the best solution will depend on what x & y are. If easy readability / concise code is your goal then this or other answers given should be fine. If however x & y were expensive function calls then it would be better to do something more like what you have done to avoid calling the function twice.

Comment: mmm... if `x` and `y` are simple expressions, then yes. Otherwise, no.

Comment: @Christian If they are not simple expressions, e. g. involve a function call, the call is performed twice, which might not be the wanted thing.

Comment: @Christian, `x` could be `compare_thousands_of_matrices()` and `y` could be `check_slow_server_response()`, for instance.

Comment: You could assign the result (value returned by the function) to variables `x` and `y`, so any function involved just get evaluated once.

Comment: If the result of each expression is large, why store a reference to it? And you will still need to evaluate the truthiness of it twice.

Comment: @2rs2ts Assuming the result of the expressions are going to be a `bool`, then you can store it.

Comment: @Christian I'll admit that less than 20% of the python code I read and write uses `True`/`False` in conditional statements :) but yes if they are static objects and already have been allocated, sure.

Comment: @2rs2ts good point. Then this approach will be recommended for non-expensive `x` and `y`.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that sometimes "x or y" is sometimes a simpler expression than literally saying x or y. For example. If x is `age >= 50` and y is `age > 20` then `x or y` is simply `age > 20` which happens to be the same as y, but will get caught by the x if clause if necessary since it's evaluated first

Comment: In this case the "elif y:" can be replaced by "else:"

Comment: @kundor I thought about that afterwards as well, it's functionally equivalent, but one less evaluation if you don't hit the if x condition.

Answer (score 7):

You could wrap some of it in a function:

```
def do_stuff():
    if x:
        ...do something1
        return True
    elif y:
        ...do something2
        return True
    else:
        return False

if do_stuff():
    ..do something3
```

Or all of it in a function:

```
def do_stuff()
    if x:
        ...do something1
    elif y:
        ...do something2
    else:
        return

    ..do something3
```

Comment: You can also suggest [like this](http://codepad.org/znUia6q5), view my deleted answer.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan: Although it becomes hard to justify the meaning of the return value in that case

Comment: yes So I deleted my answer within a minute. It is confusing at first and some programmers will dislike it like yoda-notations. But still I wanted to share so I commented.

Answer (score 6):

```
if x or y:
    dosomethig1() if x else dosomething2()
    dosomething3()
```

Of course, this does evaluate `x.__nonzero__` twice.  Usually that's not a big deal, but if it is expensive, you can always evaluate that upfront and save it to a temporary variable.

Comment: If `x and y`, `dosomething2()` is skipped with yur solution.

Comment: I disagree with the if ... else structure. Not x doesn't mean y.

Comment: @glglgl -- Yes, I know.  It's skipped in OPs too.

Comment: @Theox -- In this case, yes it does because it is in the `if x or y` clause.  One of them has to be true(ish).  If it's not `x`, then its `y`

Answer (score 6):

In the spirit of offering a completely different solution to those already proposed, you could set up a list structured dictionaries which allows you to set up multiple cases bound to your predefined "somethings"

```
cases = [
    {'condition' : x, 'action' : something1},
    {'condition' : not x and y, 'action' : something2},
    {'condition' : x or y, 'action' : something3},
]

for c in cases:
    if c['condition']: c['action']
```

I actually really like this method (and I've only just discovered it when trying to come up with a unique answer to this question, thanks!) - it's really obvious which case is bound to which action, and it's easy to add several more cases without adding any more if/else statements.

Comment: Same problem as ChrisProsser's answer - this works if `x` and `y` are simple, but if they're actually expensive function calls you'll have to extract them out into variables first, so they don't get called multiple times.  And even then, _all_ of those conditionals are going to get run, which you might not want.

Comment: Excellent qualifications Izkata!

Comment: If you use make `cases` a plain list of tuples bundling (lambda) functions for the conditions and the functions implementing the matching code, you can implement the actual loop as just `results = [action() for (condition, action) in cases if condition(x,y)]`. One nice aspect of this approach to turn code into data is that you can easily do things like counting the number of cases or enumerating the registered conditions or the like. This works well for command interpreters (think IRC clients which can be extended with custom commands).

Answer (score 4):

For all of these suggestions and any others you come up with, note that if `x` and `y` are expensive expressions:

```
if askTheServer() or readTheOneGigabyteConfigFile():
   ...
```

you can assign the values these expressions return to quick-to-evaluate variables first:

```
x = askTheServer()
y = readTheOneGigabyteConfigFile()
if x or y :
   ...
```

Answer (score 2):

```
either_true = x or y
if x:
  ...do something1
elif y:
  ...do something2
if either_true:
  ..do something3
```

Comment: Both `x or y` and `any([x, y])` mean the same even with non-booleans.

Answer (score 2):

I would wrap the ..do somethings in functions and write one if-elif:

```
def do_x():
  .. do something 1
  .. do something 3

def do_y():
  .. do something 2
  .. do something 3

if x:
   do_x()
elif y:
   do_y()
```

This is nice if the .. do somethings involve a lot of stuff.

Answer (score 0):

if do something is quite short, like do(1), do(2) or something like that, you can just do it like this:

```
(x and (do(1), x) or y and (do(2), y)) and do(3)
```